# Which approach in React is better?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below both code does exactly same but in different way. There is an onChange event listener on an input component. In first approach I am shallow cloning the items from state then doing changes over it and once changes are done I am updating the items with clonedItems with changed property.

In second approach I didn't cloned and simply did changes on state items and then updated the state accordingly. Since directly (without setState) changing property of state doesn't call updating lifecycles in react, I feel second way is better as I am saving some overhead on cloning.

```
handleRateChange = (evnt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {
          dataset: { type },
          value,
        } = evnt.target;
        const { items } = this.state;
        const clonedItems = Array.from(items);
        clonedItems.map((ele: NetworkItem) => {
          if (ele.nicType === type) {
            ele.rate = Number(value);
          }
        });
        this.setState({ items: clonedItems });
      };
```

OR

```
handleRateChange = (evnt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const {
      dataset: { type },
      value,
    } = evnt.target;
    const { items } = this.state;
    items.map((ele: NetworkItem) => {
      if (ele.nicType === type) {
        ele.rate = Number(value);
      }
    });
    this.setState({ items });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
this.setState(state => {
  const list = state.list.map(item => item + 1);

  return {
    list,
  };
});
```

if you need more info about using arrays on states, please read this: [How to manage React State with Arrays](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the input is generally a bad practice, however cloning in the first example is a bit of an overkill. You don't really need to clone the array to achieve immutability, how about something like that:

```
handleRateChange = (evnt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {
          dataset: { type },
          value,
        } = evnt.target;
        const { items } = this.state;

        const processedItems = items.map((ele: NetworkItem) => {
          if (ele.nicType === type) {
            return {
              ...ele,
              rate: Number(value)
            };
          } else {
            return ele;
          }
        });

        this.setState({ items: processedItems });
      };
```

It can be refactored of course, I left it like this to better illustrate the idea. Which is, instead of cloning the `items` before mapping, or modifying its content, you can return a new object from the `map`'s callback and assign the result to a new variable.

Comment: The code that I shared is modifying objects in array itself, and I am not getting subset out if it.